# How to define the name for a nested stack in CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

When the nested stack is created within another stack, it obtains the name like:

```
<name-of-the-parent-stack>-<resource-name>-<UUID>
```

what doesn't look nice. Meantime I can not find any property of the "[AWS::CloudFormation::Stack](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html)" type where I could specify the desired name. Is it possible to define its name or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't an alternative.